Ajax function does not use the new generated OpenIdConnect.nonce token
I recently implemented office 365 authentication on my company's intranet portal (MVC .net 4.8)
Here is the code:
private static readonly string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
private static readonly string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
private static readonly string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
private static readonly string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
private static readonly string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

readonly string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

[Obsolete]
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
               AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
               {
                   var code = context.Code;
                   ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                   string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                   AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                   AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                       code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId).Result;

                   return Task.FromResult(0);
               }

            }
        });
}


But office 365 tokens expire after one hour. And whenever I make an ajax call after the token expires...
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    success: function (data) {
        //SUCCESS
    },
    error: function () {
        //ERROR
    }
});


...even though a new token is generated...
Tokens
...I get a bad request because the expired token is still being used
Has anyone had the same problem?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Regards
